# Admob Interstiial ads impressions are very less in Admob dashboard

Tags: java, android, admob

I have InterstitialManger class and  InterstailBackup class for showing inter ads in my app when Interstitial class ads failed to load ads then i am showing ads by InterstialBackup manger class in activities  , Ads are showing perfectly in the app but the problem is impression in not recording , suppose in-app ad is shown 100 times but is admob dashBoard impression count is  7 , 8 , 10 very less.

Here are my codes

InterstitialManger class :--

Same implementation for InterstialBackup

```
public class InterstitialManager {
  private static final String TAG = "InterstitialManager";
  public InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
  private boolean adLoaded;
  private String adUnitId;
  InterstitialManagerBackup interstitialManagerBackup ;

    public InterstitialManager(Context context, String adUnitId) {
        this.adUnitId = adUnitId;
        loadAd(context);
    }

 private void loadAd(Context context) {
     InterstitialAd.load(context, adUnitId, new AdRequest.Builder().build(),
     new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onAdLoaded(InterstitialAd ad) {
       interstitialAd = ad;
            adLoaded = true;
                        interstitialManagerBackup = new InterstitialManagerBackup(context,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
                        Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad loaded"+interstitialAd.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        super.onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad failed"+loadAdError.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }

    public void showAd(Activity activity) {
        if (adLoaded && interstitialAd != null) {
            interstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAdImpression() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad impression recorded");
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                   
                    interstitialAd = null;
                      loadAd(activity.getApplicationContext());     
                    Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad dismissed");
                }
            });
            interstitialAd.show(activity);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad not loaded yet. Loading now...");
            loadAd(activity.getApplicationContext());
        }
    }
}
```

In application class i am loading ad:-

`

```
 public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private InterstitialManager interstitialManager;
    private InterstitialManagerBackup interstitialManagerBackup;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        interstitialManager = new InterstitialManager(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        interstitialManagerBackup = new InterstitialManagerBackup(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");

    }

    public InterstitialManager getInterstitialManager() {
        return interstitialManager;
    }

    public InterstitialManagerBackup getInterstitialManagerBackup() {
        return interstitialManagerBackup;
    }
}`
```

In Activity showing ads like this:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ` private InterstitialManager interstitialManager;
    Button showAdbutton,nextActButton;
    private InterstitialManagerBackup interstitialManagerBackup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        showAdbutton = findViewById(R.id.btn_show_ad);
        nextActButton = findViewById(R.id.second_act);



        

        MyApplication application = (MyApplication) getApplication();
        interstitialManager = application.getInterstitialManager();
        interstitialManagerBackup = application.getInterstitialManagerBackup();


        showAdbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (interstitialManager.interstitialAd!= null){
                    showInterstitialAd();
                }else{
                    showInterstitailBackup();
                }

            }
        });


    }

    private void showInterstitialAd() {
        interstitialManager.showAd(this);
    }
    private  void showInterstitailBackup(){
        interstitialManagerBackup.showAd(MainActivity.this);
    }
}
```

what is wrong in this implementation why ads impression is not recording

I am tried to show ads with above classes, i want the correct ads impression that ads are shown in my app but the count is too low

Comment: Are you sure that you are using real ad unit ids on production? Is `onAdImpression` called in `FullScreenContentCallback`?

Comment: Yes..i am using original ad unit id ..in onAdinmpresion i am get log line.   Every time when  ad is shown on onAdImpression method is being called but ...no impression is recording in admob dash board